# Auto-populate today's date in a cell based on another cell

Tags: excel-formula

In my excel file, I'm wondering if it's possible to automatically populate today's date whenever there's data in another cell

I have this formula: `=IFERROR(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A50),1,TODAY(),0), "")` on the `C2` cell and this is how it looks as an example:

| Customer Name | Order Number | Date Ordered |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer A | 1 | 9/15/2023 |
| Customer B | 2 | 9/15/2023 |
| Customer C | 3 | 9/15/2023 |

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrTyN.png. It's working as I want it to. it shows the date the item was added. However, when the day changes, the values in the cell also change into today’s date. I know that it’s the `TODAY()` part of my formula but I can’t think of anything to put. Is it possible for that not to change?

Any help would be appreciated. TYIA

Comment: The last I knew, the only way to stop Today() from updating itself each time the page is opened on another day requires the use of VBA.  What you are looking for is a way to add todays date and LOCK IT so it does not change?

Comment: Yes. Preferably a formula that when I put a name in `column A` today's date would show up in `column C` that doesn't change the next day. I know that the formula I have is not the best fit for it, which is why I'm looking for recommendations as I'm still learning.